# валидация полей

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени суток, есть скрипт на проверку поля логин к примеру

```
var jVal = {
    'login' : function() {


        var nameInfo = $('#login');
        var ele = $('input#login');

        if(ele.val().length < 3 || ele.val().length > 32) {
            jVal.errors = true;
            nameInfo.removeClass('correct').addClass('error_form').show();          
        }else{
            nameInfo.removeClass('error_form').addClass('correct').show();
        }
        var  patt = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+$/g;
        if(!patt.test(ele.val())) {
            jVal.errors = true;
            nameInfo.removeClass('correct').addClass('error_form').show();          
        }else{
            nameInfo.removeClass('error_form').addClass('correct').show();
        }
    },

$('#login').change(jVal.login); // вызывает обработку
```

Работает не совсем корректно, идет проверка на кол-во символов, и на разрешаемые символы, но работает один только в зависимости что вводить. Как комплексно настроить проверку дабы выполнялись все условия?

Comment: вас точка в регулярке не смущает? оставьте чисто проверку регуляркой `([\w-]){3,32}` то же самое будет

Comment: а вообще алгоритм у вас не правильный. надо 1)проверить первое правило - не прошло показать ошибку, выход 2) второе правило - ошибка - выход 3) все ок - показываем успех. Не нужны вам else в проверках

Comment: teran, нет не смущает, вопрос ведь в другом состоит, как выполнять одно и другое условие одновременно не запихивая все в один if()

Comment: пардоньте, про точку натупил,она же в квадратных скобках. Но второй коммент по делу будет.

Comment: teran, в том то и дело что при появлении второго условия первое не срабатывает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам не надо пытаться показывать форму после каждой проверки. Надо сначала все проверить, и в конце после непосредственных проверок показать или не показать.

можно сделать как то так (не проверял).

```
var jVal = {
'login' : function() {


    var nameInfo = $('#login');
    var ele = $('input#login');

    var errors = false;
    nameInfo.removeClass("correct error_form");

    if(ele.val().length < 3 || ele.val().length > 32) {
        errors = true;
    }

    var  patt = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+$/g;
    if(!patt.test(ele.val())) {
        errors = true;
    }

    var cls = errors ? "error_form" : "correct";
    nameInfo.addClass(cls).show();
},
```

но повторюсь, каков смысл проверять отдельно длину, если регуляркой ее также можно проверить `/^([\w-.]){3,32}$/` ? Вы же не выводите различные сообщения на каждый тип проверки.

Comment: так работает, большое спасибо)